# (discord.js) How do I pick two different users from the guild?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

So here's my command's code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test1',
    cooldown: '30',
    description: 'NaN',
    execute(message) {
        message.delete({ timeout: 10 });
        const ranUser1 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
        const ranUser2 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;

        const max = 100;
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
        message.channel.send(`${ranUser1} ${ranUser2} ${number}%.`);
        console.log('\nExecuted command: !test');
    },
};
```

And what I want to do is, when variable `ranUser1` is equal to `ranUser2` I want to "reroll" ranUser1 and then send the message with the changed variable. And I want to reroll this variable until it's not equal to `ranUser2`. The expected output would be to ensure two different users are selected instead of the same one twice.

Comment: can you specify the problem more clear?

Comment: I have a command in my bot that randomly chooses 2 people from a guild and says they are x% best friends. The problem is sometimes variable ```ranUser1``` is equal to ```ranUser2``` and I get something like "*User1* is best friends with *User1*". What I wanted to do is when variable ```ranUser1``` is equal to ```ranUser2``` I wanted my bot to choose another person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not a complete expert on discord.js but I think I know the way to do so:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test1',
    cooldown: '30',
    description: 'NaN',
    execute(message) {
        message.delete({ timeout: 10 });
    
        function roll() {
        var ranUser1 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user; // constants aren't ideal if you want to be able to change them later
        var ranUser2 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
        if (ranUser1==ranUser2) { // you can do === for better accuracy
           roll()
        };
        };

        roll();

        const max = 100;
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
        message.channel.send(`${ranUser1} ${ranUser2} ${number}%.`);
        console.log('\nExecuted command: !test');
    },
```

Not the best at making code beautiful but this should do.

Comment: Oh yeah lemme fix it rq

Answer (score 3):

A while loop should work. It will keep choosing a random user until it's not the same as the second user. You do have to dedine `ranUser1` to a `let` instead of `const` since you will need to change it.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'test1',
    cooldown: '30',
    description: 'NaN',
    execute(message) {
        message.delete({ timeout: 10 });
        let ranUser1 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user; // Converted to var so it can be changed
        const ranUser2 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
        while (ranUser1.id === ranUser2.id) {
            ranUser1 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
        }
        const max = 100;
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
        message.channel.send(`${ranUser1} ${ranUser2} ${number}%.`);
        console.log('\nExecuted command: !test');
    },
};
```

Comment: Use let instead of var.

Comment: Single line comments are `//` in javascript, not `#` like in some other languages

Comment: @Levi_OP Oh, oops. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A quick function that will reroll the variable until they aren't equal:

```js
var ranUser1;
var ranUser2;
function check() {
    ranUser1 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
    ranUser2 = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
    if (ranUser1 === ranUser2) return check()
    const max = 100;
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
    message.channel.send(`${ranUser1} ${ranUser2} ${number}%.`);
    console.log('\nExecuted command: !test');
}
```

This way if they are the same it will attempt to pick two different users until it gets ones that are different.

Here's an example with random number to show it in action:

```js
var ranUser1;
var ranUser2;
function check() {
    ranUser1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1
    ranUser2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1
    if (ranUser1 === ranUser2) return check()
    const max = 100;
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
    console.log(`${ranUser1} ${ranUser2} ${number}%.`);
    console.log('\nExecuted command: !test');
}
check()
```